# Populating an array Using Polymorphism

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

Here is my code. I did my work a bit off. I was supposed to not just do one applicant, I was supposed to do many and I was supposed to populate the applicants into 2 different arrays, one for graduates, and one for undergraduates. I need help figuring out how to make an empty array and fill up applicants in those. A start would help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollegeApplicant
{
String applicantName;
String collegeName;
public String getApplicantName()
{
    return applicantName;

}
public void setApplicantName(String applicantName)
{
    this.applicantName = applicantName;

}
public String getCollegeName()
{
    return collegeName;

}
public void setCollegeName(String collegeName)
{
    this.collegeName = collegeName;

}
public void checkCollege()
{
    int choice;
    Graduate g = new Graduate();
    Undergraduate ug = new Undergraduate();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1. Undergraduate");
    System.out.println("2. Graduate");
    System.out.println("enter your choice ");
    choice = input.nextInt();
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter SAT marks :");
        ug.SAT = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter GPA marks :");
        ug.GPA = input.nextDouble();

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the origin of college:");
        g.collegeOrigin = input.next();
        System.out.println("Status :" + g.checkCollege());

    }

}
public class Undergraduate
{
    double SAT;
    double GPA;

}
public class Graduate
{
    String collegeOrigin;
    String checkCollege()
    {
        String information = null;
        if (collegeName.equals(collegeName)) information = "Applicant is applying from inside";
        else information = "Applicant is applying from outside";
        return information;

    }

}

}
```

The Client

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollegeApplicantClient extends CollegeApplicant
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TestCollege tc = new TestCollege();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of applicant ");
    tc.setApplicantName(input.next());
    System.out.println("enter the college name of applicant ");
    tc.setCollegeName(input.next());
    tc.checkCollege();

  }

 }
```

Here is an example of the possible output

```
Name: Joe

College Applied to: Harvard

SAT:    5

GPA:    2

Name: Tom

College Applied to: Yale

College of Origin: NYU – from outside
```

I need to be able to put the graduates in an array and the undergrads in an array. Then display it when it's all done

Comment: It would help if you showed us the input, the output, and what you expected the output to be --- that is, why you feel the output is wrong.

Comment: Just did it If it helps

Comment: Use an `ArrayList<Graduate>` and `ArrayList<Undergraduate>`. Store using `ArrayList<T>.add(T t)`.